# A 3-dimensional principal value integral

Tags: numerical-integration, singularity, mathematica-online

I am trying to find a principal value integral of the following form in Mathematica. $f(z)$ is a smooth function. The problem is that Mathematica is very slow in this computation.

$\int_1^2 dx\int_1^3 dz \int_1^2 dy \frac{z f(z)}{x(x+z)(x-y)}$

Suppose that $f(z)$ is 1, then one can take the integral over $z$ analytically and the numerical computation of the triple integral reduces to the numerical computation of a 2-dimensional integral. In this case, Mathematica is pretty fast. I am wondering what I should do in the case where $f(z)$ is not 1 but a smooth function so one has to compute the integral over $z$ numerically. I am wondering if someone can help me with this. Thank you!

Comment: If $f(z)=1$, then the three-dimensional improper integral under consideration diverges. I have never seen  a principal value notion for multiple improper integrals with a  singularity which is not a one-point singularity. See [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=Cauchy+principal+value&title=Special:Search&ns0=1) for info.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the integrals over $x$ and $y$ analytically:

```
Assuming[1 <= z <= 3, 
  Integrate[(z f[z])/(x (x + z) (x - y)),
            {x, 1, 2}, {y, 1, 2},
            PrincipalValue -> True]]

(*    1/2 f[z] (-Log[2]^2 + Log[(1 + z)/(2 + z)]^2)    *)
```

With a specific definition of $f(z)$ you can now proceed either by analytic or numerical integration. For example,

```
f[z_] = Cos[z];
NIntegrate[1/2 f[z] (-Log[2]^2 + Log[(1 + z)/(2 + z)]^2), {z, 1, 3}]
(*    0.151575    *)
```

Comment: You calculate an iterated integral, making use of principal value. there are  5 other iterated integrals here. How about these?

Comment: Let us put `f[z_]:=1/z`. Then `Assuming[1 <= y <= 2, 
  Integrate[1/(x (x + z) (x - y)), {x, 1, 2}, {z, 1, 3}, 
   PrincipalValue -> True]];NIntegrate[%, {y, 1, 2}]` produces `-0.208647-2.99985*10^-16 I`, but `Assuming[1<=z<=3,Integrate[1/(x (x+z) (x-y)),{x,1,2},{y,1,2},PrincipalValue->True]];NIntegrate[%, {z, 1, 3}]` results in `-0.390059`.

Comment: @Roman Thank you so much for your answer! I computed the integral numerically over z first and found a different answer. That is the same as what the other user found.

Comment: I don't think you can compute the principal component numerically – this part has to be done analytically. So I'm not surprised that you got a different answer.

Comment: @user64494 inside a [`CompoundExpression`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CompoundExpression.html) the symbol `%` refers to the previous complete expression, not the previous part of the same CompoundExpression. Your results are wrong.
Easy experiment: execute `2`, then execute `5; %` and see that the result is 2, not 5.

Comment: I've checked all six iterated integrals: $dx\,dy\,dz$, $dx\,dz\,dy$, $dy\,dx\,dz$, $dy\,dz\,dx$, $dz\,dx\,dy$, $dz\,dy\,dx$. They all give the same result.